# Purpose of 'tf.get_default_session()'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

This question is about running sessions in TensorFlow.

I am confused about what purpose `tf.get_default_session().run(...)` serves over `tf.Session().run(...)`.

Can't all cases of [`tf.get_default_session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_default_session) be replaced with [`tf.Session()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't.

`tf.get_default_session` returns the innermost session already active in the current running thread. Hence you should already have an active session.

`tf.Session` instead, creates a new session in the current running thread.

Comment: Ah okay so am I right in thinking that if there's some working code that uses `tf.get_default_session` from a single session and I replace it with `tf.Session` then I create two separate sessions? And if that is the case what could go wrong if you work with two separate sessions?

Comment: Yes, you're right. A lot of things could go wrong. Tensorflow assumes a single session has the control of all the GPU resources, if you use 2 sessions then concurrency problems like race conditions arise.